# Calling one templated function isn't working

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, std-function

I don't know how to call function `call`.

It's a templated class, with a templated function call.  But how can I use this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <functional>

template <typename Result> class Imp {
    template <typename ...Args> int call(std::function<Result(Args...)> func, Args... args) {
        return 0;
    }
};

int f(double a, double b) {
    return (int)a+b;
}

int main() {
    Imp<int> a;
    a.call<double, double>(f, 1., 1.); //!
}
```

---

```
error C2784: 'int Imp<int>::call(std::function<Result(Args...)>,Args...)' : could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' from 'overloaded function type'
      with
      [
          Result=int
      ]
       : see declaration of 'Imp<int>::call'
```

Comment: @sp2danny I suspect the choice of english words gave this question a certain _smell_.  Fixing now...

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a a `function pointer` to `std::function` like that ( see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271728/how-to-pass-member-function-pointer-to-stdfunction) )

Change it to something like this :

```
template <typename Result> class Imp {
public:
    template <class Func,typename ...Args> int call(Func f, Args... args) {
        return 0;
    }
};
int f(double a, double b) {return (int)a+b;}
int main() {
    Imp<int> a;
    a.call(f, 1., 1.); //!
}
```

[ideone](https://ideone.com/Eh2QqO)

Or :

```
#include <functional>
template <typename Result> class Imp {
public:
    template <typename ...Args> int call(std::function<Result(Args...)> f, Args... args) {
        return 0;
    }
};
int f(double a, double b) {return (int)a+b;}
int main() {
    Imp<int> a;
    a.call(std::function<int(double,double)>(f), 1., 1.); //!
}
```

Comment: You **can** cast from a function to a `std::function`.  You link to a question about casting a _member function_.